# proper use of class (csv reader example)

Tags: python, csv

I've done the following CSV reader class:

```
class CSVread(object):
    filtered = []

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def get_file(self):
        try:
            with open(self.file, "r") as f:
                self.reader = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter = ";")]
                return self.reader
        except IOError as err:
            print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror))
        return

    def get_num_rows(self):
        print(sum(1 for row in self.reader))
```

Which can be used with the following example:

```
datacsv = CSVread("data.csv") # ; seperated file

for row in datacsv.get_file(): # prints all the rows
    print(row)

datacsv.get_num_rows() # number of rows in data.csv
```

My goal is to filter out the content of the csv  file (data.csv) by filtering column 12 by the keyword "00GG". I can get it to work outside the class like this:

```
with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ";")
    filtered = []
    filtered = filter((lambda row: row[12] in ("00GG")), list(reader))
```

Code below returns an empty list (filtered) when it's defined inside the class:

```
def filter_data(csv_file):
    filtered = filter((lambda row: row[12] in ("00GGL")), self.reader)
    return filtered
```

Feedback for the existing code is also appreciated.

Comment: You will need to call get_file before using filter_data, as you have not initialized the reader.

Comment: @strongbad Does your `filter_data` function have the `self` argument? Is this the actual code where you are getting issue? If not please provide actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that in the first filter example you are searching for `00GG` whereas in the second one you are searching for `00GGL`?

Regardless, if you want to define `filter_data()` within the class you should write is as a method of the class. That means that it takes a `self` parameter, not a `csv_file`:

```
def filter_data(self):
    filtered = filter((lambda row: row[12] in ("00GGL")), self.reader)
    return filtered
```

Making it more general:

```
def filter_data(self, column, values):
    return filter((lambda row: row[column] in values), self.reader)
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
datacsv.filter_data(12, ('00GGL',))
```

which should work if the input data does indeed contain rows with `00GGL` in column 12.

Note that `filter_data()` should only be called *after* `get_file()` otherwise there is no `self.reader`. Unless you have a good reason not to read in the data when the `CSVread` object is created (e.g. you are aiming for lazy evaluation), you should read it in then. Otherwise, set `self.reader = []` which will prevent failure in other methods.

Comment: thank you! this kind of feedback I was hoping for. You noticed my "00GGL" typo as well, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries @strongbad. Was the typo the problem?

Comment: nope, it was just a result of copypasting and rewriting stuff here.